# Bits and pieces of maps?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

Your friend texts you this image. What does it mean?
[image]
Note: I created this puzzle. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row

> consists of 8 hexagons either filled or empty.

This is reminiscent of

> Binary digits representing ASCII bytes.

In fact, they are

> and they spell "Get out of the house!"

With a minor

> mistake of encoding a g instead of an h in the word "the"

Comment: Oh my bad. But if you figured out the rest of the puzzle I feel that the error is negligible